System.out.print not working inside while loop
I'm writing program where you keep entering numbers until you find adjacent duplicates, at which point the message "Duplicate found" is displayed. The message "please enter a number" wont display from System.out.print from inside while loop.
package FindingDuplicates;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingDuplicates {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        double input = in.nextDouble();
        while(in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double previous = input;
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            input = in.nextDouble();
            if(previous == input)
            {
                System.out.print("Duplicate found");
            }
        }
    }

}


Sorry. Yeah, System.out.print is not working inside while loop.

When you check in.hasNextDouble() inside the loop, it checks if there is another double value to read from the input. However, this condition will only be false when there's no more input available, which means it will only exit the loop when the user doesn't enter any more numbers.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingDuplicates {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        double previous = in.nextDouble();
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            if (previous == input) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate found");
                break;
            }
            previous = input;
        }
    }
}


You need to reassign the first input to previous. I suggest you not use hasNextDouble for terminal input.  Just break out of the loop when a double is found.
public class FindingDuplicates {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        double previous = in.nextDouble();
        while (true) {
           
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            if(previous == input)
            {
                System.out.println("Duplicate found");
                break;
            }
            previous = input;
        }
    }

}

